# node-red converting buffer to value

Tags: node-red

I read multiple 64bit counter from a switch using snmp. I get the values stored in a buffer. But the size of the buffer is not as apected 8 bytes so I can't convert it using 'buf.readDoubleBE'. The buffer grows while the counter increases.
Following example is the output of the snmp subtree node (just the first two objects)

```
msg : Object
    object
    host: "192.168.0.11"
    name: "SWHAR"
    _msgid: "3a45e09a.957c9"
    oid: "1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.6"
    payload: array[33]
        [0 … 9]
            0: object
                oid: "1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.6.1"
                value: buffer[4]raw
                    0: 0x0
                    1: 0xb9
                    2: 0xda
                    3: 0x4b
            1: object
                oid: "1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.6.2"
                value: buffer[1]raw
                    0: 0x0
            2: object ....cut
```

Any hints how to convert it to the Counter value?
I'm using following function to separate the array into individual messages.
I already tried using 'readDoubleBE(0,true)' without reading the documentation to the end ;-) it stops immediately the Docker container.
Without noAssert I got an index out of range error.

```
function shootMsg(element, index, array) {
    node.send ({payload: element.value, topic:'SwMetrics/' + msg.name + '/' + index});
}

msg.payload.forEach(shootMsg);
```

Comment: You say the 64bit value is a counter so it will always be an integer?

Comment: Also the largest integer type that NodeJS can support is 32bit

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can't just treat each `value` key the same, from the example you have given the 1st is 4 bytes long, but the second is only 1 byte.

This is why `getDouble()` is failing because it is trying to read 2 bytes from the second `value` and there is only one.

And as I said in the comments. The largest integer value that can be handled in NodeJS is a 32bit Int.

**EDIT:**

Having looked at your previous question, I'm going to guess that the 4 byte `value` is actually a IP address so you should be reading it as 4 seperate bytes with `readInt8()`